# socket connect_error : [Error: xhr poll error] with server behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

My React Native 0.66 app uses `socket.io-client 4.4.1` to connect with nodejs `socket.io 4.4.3` server. Here is the socket client code at in app:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
let socUrl = 'https://mydomain.top'; //<<==domain name for the nodejs server 
let _socket = io(socUrl, {. //<<==option to establish socket to nodejs 14.x server
  path:'/sokt',
});  

_socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("socket.id in chat : ", _socket.id); //<<== never fired because no connection
});
_socket.on("connect_error", (err)=>{
  console.log("socket connect_error : ", err) //<<==[Error: xhr poll error]
})
```

Tried other option in establishing socket such as `secure:true, rejectUnauthorized:false` and the error is the same or error of `timeout`.

The socket on server side is:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
const {Server} = require("socket.io");  //socket.io ver 4.4.3
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://mydomain.top" //<<==domain name for the nodejs server
  }
});
....
httpServer.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

The nodejs server is behind nginx reverse proxy and proxy-pass seems working fine. Here is the config of nginx reverse proxy:

```
location ~ ^/(sokt|socket.io) {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
```

UPDATE: here is the nginx access log entry of connect request from React Native front end:

```
xx.xx.92.84 - - [19/Feb/2022:00:24:48 +0800] "GET /sokt/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NyDfdOt HTTP/1.1" 404 144 "-" "okhttp/4.9.1" "-""127.0.0.1:5000" "127.0.0.1:5000""-" "http_authorization"
```

UPADTE1: output from curl remotely:

```
curl "https://mydomain.top/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"
0{"sid":"8wYqHl9Lc_rLCnksAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000}%
```

Comment: Hi, did you check connection from postman? Did it work?

Comment: Hi `Mamed_gibago`, I didn't check the connection from postman. I checked the nginx access log and there are entries about connect request from the React Native app. I just updated with some of the nginx access log.

Comment: So you've just updated the code you'd sent from curl and I need the response or error log in curl or nginx log. Please try to send url request and parameters from postman or write logs that I mentioned, an we will see the problem is from where. Maybe its in side of network. Good luck.

Comment: Both the client and server shall be configured with exactly the same `path:/sokt`